# Swift FileManager.ContentsOfDirectory returns nil

Tags: swift

I am very new to Apple development and I am writing a simple app where i am trying to access certain images inside my project. To do this I made a simple function which returns (in theory) the file names in an array.

```
class Tools{
    public func GetFiles(filePath : String) -> Array<NSString>{
        let fm = FileManager.default
        let path = Bundle.main.resourcePath! + filePath

        let items = try? fm.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: path)

        return items! as Array<NSString>;

    }
}
```

And in my main class I am calling this function and passing along the directory where it can find my files

```
class LoadingView: UIViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    let tool = Tools()
        var logoAnim = tool.GetFiles(filePath: "/Path/To/My/Files");
  }
}
```

That is all I'm doing code-wise... Now here is how i have my asset structure

[image]

And I also made sure to include each file as a target member of this product

[image]

When I debug this it returns nil every time. Can someone help me understand what am I doing wrong? Is there a special way I need to reference the path, or, am I missing an extra step?

Comment: Those yellow folders in your Xcode project are just a logical grouping. They do not define any kind of directory layout in the bundled app. All of those resources are directly in the root of your app bundle.

Comment: Once built, the resources are packed into an app Bundle. Once installed, the app Bundle is placed in some hidden directory. So, you cannot access resources through absolute path. Better read the documentation of [Bundle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle).

Comment: thank you both for the help. I come from Windows development so everything is new to me. This article really helps.